# MAUI Blazor - Use Webview as component

Tags: webview, maui, maui-blazor

I have a MAUI .NET6 application with blazor pages and components, and I would like to display a kind of web browser inside a page, in order to display some internet content.

I tried to use the BlazorWebView, but I couldn't figure out how to use a XAML component inside a blazor component.

For now I have an iframe, but some internet content is blocked. I would like to have like a real browser.

Have you some ideas how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed XAML inside of Razor pages. Whenever you are inside of a `BlazorWebView` you will need to find a "web way" to fix whatever you're doing. So that would indeed be an `iframe` or something like that.

Another way around it would be to navigate to a .NET MAUI native page and show a `WebView` on that, but seeing how you describe things, that is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed I haven't any XAML page. I would need to code lot of stuffs and my XAML skills are a bit old. But I've found some js code for webbrowser [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JSBrowser/tree/v1.0). I'll try to make a blazor wrapper.

Comment: Dumb question @Gerald, how do you create a Native MAUI page in a Blazor MAUI app.

Comment: @Igal Just create a xaml page and you can use the Xamarin routing stuffs. Blazor MAUI is just a single xaml page with a webview