# Use Native XAML on .NET MAUI Blazor

Tags: .net, maui, maui-blazor

I saw in some of the presentations pages using both Native and Blazor in the same application. However, when I try doing it I can't figure out how to add XAML native page to the application, how Gerald mentions in this question [MAUI Blazor - Use Webview as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73567743/maui-blazor-use-webview-as-component)

Comment: *"how to add XAML native page to the application"* See any .Net Maui tutorial or video. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin&pivots=devices-android. Bottom line: Maui pages using xaml is what one typically *starts* with when creating a Maui app. Learn how to do that first. *Then* follow instructions for adding Blazor to a Maui app.

Comment: So basically there is no way to modify my existing Blazor MAUI to have one native page, it will be easier to create a regular MAUI App and add a blazor page?

Comment: I think you can do what you want. But I've never tried it, and no one has come along and posted how to do it. So the way for you to learn what the app needs to look like, is to do what you just asked. After doing that, compare your original app, and the regular Maui app. Probably you can figure out the needed changes in your original. If you succeed, please add Your Answer below, to help others in this situation. Good luck!